# How I can split Tabel to multi table-based columns number ASPOSE words .NET

Tags: c#, aspose.words

I have a table created inside a word file by HTML and this table has a large number of columns,
how can I split the table into more than one table by a specified number of columns?
Scenario 1:
My table has only 20 columns I want to split it into three tables each table have 9 columns
Main Tabel - with cols 1,2,3,4…20…etc.
Result
Table 1 - with cols 1,2,3,4, …9.
Table 2 - with cols 1,2,3,4, …9.
Table 3- with cols 1,2,
please note that I use ASPOSE.NET word (c#)
Thanks, and regards,

Comment: Please look to the main question
 https://forum.aspose.com/t/how-i-can-split-tabel-to-multi-table-based-columns-number/239872?u=jassarmahmoud

Answer (score 1):

In MS Word documents as well as in Aspose.Words DOM the rows in the tables are independent, i.e. each row can have different number of cells. So there is not column concept. However, you can emulate the work with columns using Aspose.Words API, For example see [how to work with table columns](https://docs.aspose.com/words/net/working-with-columns-and-rows/#work-with-columns) using Aspose.Words.
in your case, you can clone the original table and remove unnecessary columns from the original table and from it's copy.

Comment: thank you @Alexey